# How to return the passed variable url parameter in json

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask app. I want it to write the variable parameters passed through the URL end point to an out-file.

I tried it writing to an out-file, but the name passed in URL endpoint is not getting printed in the out-file. Please suggest the way so that the out-file could be dynamically altered when passed the variable endpoint

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import json
import uuid 


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/<string:name>')
def get_stats(name):
    proceuudi = uuid.uuid4()

    stat = [
        {
            'process_id': str(proceuudi),
            'process_name': 'name' 
        }
    ]

    with open('data.txt', 'w+') as f:  # writing JSON object
        json.dump(stat, f)
    return jsonify({'stats':stat})
app.run(port = 8500)
```

When hitting the url  http://127.0.0.1:2700/generate
The output i am getting in outfile is

```
[{"process_name": "favicon.ico", "process_id": "82daa01c-bb2d-444c-9b44-a8880200cb2a"}]
```

Here the "process_name" should be generate as passed in URL parameter. But i am getting favicon.ico

Comment: I think you may have posted an older version of your code. Should 'name' be in quotes in your initialization of stat? Do you intend to append each 'stat' to the end of the file every time the endpoint is hit?

Comment: @chris.va.rao I need to dynamically alter the name as passed in url parameter. It should take the name string passed through url endpoint.

Comment: In the above code, the name parameter is never referenced.

Comment: chris.va.rao was saying that 'process_name': 'name' should NOT have 'name' in quotes. He is correct. See my answer to your question.

Comment: @coltoneakins It Helped me a lot. Thanks for the help.
It is working fine in Mozilla Firefox browser too.

Comment: @coltoneakins  If we want multiple entries in .txt file. Is it possible to append all those entries in the form of key value pair inside a list:
eg:
[{"process_name": "testing", "process_id": "0325967d-010f-418e-b8e7-ced66325a5e3"},{"process_name": "testing1", "process_id": "d3c3b1bb-b706-4eb4-be2f-41d88935ae87"}]

===============================================================================================

instead of:
[{"process_name": "testing", "process_id": "0325967d-010f-418e-b8e7-ced66325a5e3"}][{"process_name": "testing1", "process_id": "d3c3b1bb-b706-4eb4-be2f-41d88935ae87"}]

Comment: @LalitBora Yes, you definitely can. But, you want to open the file in append mode using "a+". Something like with open('data.txt', 'a+') to append on each route.

Answer (score 0):

The web browser is causing this. You should try using **pdb** and setting a trace as shown below:

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import json
import uuid 
import pdb

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/<string:name>')
def get_stats(name):
    proceuudi = uuid.uuid4()

    stat = [
        {
            'process_id': str(proceuudi),
            'process_name': name 
        }
    ]

    with open('data.txt', 'w+') as f:  # writing JSON object
        pdb.set_trace()
        json.dump(stat, f)
    return jsonify({'stats':stat})
app.run(port = 8500)
```

The web browser is doing this. You are using a web browser to make a request to your Flask dev server. The way your code is set up, the file **data.txt** does receive the right output--but that output is almost immediately overwritten because the web browser automatically sends a request to the server to get the favicon for the web page. Webkit / Blink based web browsers do this.

This is the output from the command line when I make a request in my web browser (Chrome) to the server. All I am doing is visiting the link:  http://127.0.0.1:8500/cat

But, my web browser also *automatically* makes a request for the web page's favicon.

```sh
 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:8500/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Apr/2019 22:15:14] "GET /cat HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Apr/2019 22:15:14] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

See that second request? The second GET request for 'favicon.ico'? My web browser did that one automatically. This is the web browser trying to automatically grab the little icon to display in your web browser's tab menu bar for this web page. Try using a command line program like **wget** to make an HTTP request to your server. You can try something like this in a command line (on Linux, for example):

```sh
wget http://127.0.0.1:8500/cat
```

We use a command line program like wget because it will only strictly send HTTP request you tell it to. It is not like a web browser that does some stuff behind the scenes.

If you use wget to test this, your **data.txt** file looks like this:

```
[{"process_id": "30423bad-7640-441e-b608-f77f4420d07e", "process_name": "cat"}]
```

Your web browser is sending a request for the favicon of this page because it thinks it is a normal web page.